# How to run bookmarklet in Safari on iOS

Tags: ios, safari

With Chrome, the only way I can run a bookmarklet is by typing the bookmarklets name into the address bar and then clicking the suggested result. In Safari on iOS, it displays a result saying that JavaScript cannot be run from the address bar. I don't have access to an iPhone that I can continue to use to test the bookmarklets I write, but I attempted running it from the bookmarks menu in Safari and it didn't do anything.

How do I run bookmarklets on iOS in Safari?

Answer (score 3):

Apart from opening Safari manually and selecting the bookmark from your favorites, you can also pin it to your homescreen were you can tap the icon and it'll open Safari for you and run the Javascript. Although for that you need to use a slightly different address.

```
data:text/html,<script>alert('test')</script>
```

Visit the above and after the page is loaded you can then tap share and select pin to homescreen. After that you can just tap the icon.

Those are the only two ways to run JS/HTML script.

Comment: I already know how to create a bookmark with JavaScript code in the address; that's not what I'm asking for. You say you were able to run it, but HOW did you run it? That *is* what I want to know.

Comment: I updated my answer with two ways to run JS on iOS. Here's a video on how to pin it to the homescreen https://imgur.com/uRvETy1